# Trouble pasring nested values from json files using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, parsing

Trying to pull the `signing_certificate_id` field from the below json snippet, but unfortunately, the data is not making it into the excel export. The other info is making it into the csv. (there are cases where these code blocks exist twice in the same json to represent a separate environment.

Json Snippet:

```
{
  "sfg_ping::production::standard_sp_connections": [
    {
      "name": "hhhh",
      "entity_id": "https://hhhh.hhhh.com",
      "contact_info": "hhhh@hhhh.com",
      "sp_endpoint": "https://hhhh.hhhh.com/",
      "sso_initialization_and_signature_policy": {
        "sign_assertion_or_response": "assertion",
        "sp_trust_model": "unanchored",
        "signing_certificate_id": "gggggg",
        "sp_initiated": {
          "require_signed_authn_requests": false
        }
      },
```

Script being used:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\hhhh\appdev\targetfolder-json2" -Filter *.json -PipelineVariable file | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.pspath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).PSObject.Properties.Value | Select-Object @(
        @{ l = 'filename'; e = { $file.Name }}, 'Name','contact_info', 'signing_certificate_id'
    )
} | Export-Csv path\to\myexport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [*calculated property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) for getting the nested JSON property, similar to what you did for `filename`:

```sh
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\hhhh\appdev\targetfolder-json2" -Filter *.json -PipelineVariable file | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.pspath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).PSObject.Properties.Value | Select-Object @(
        @{ l = 'filename'; e = { $file.Name }}, 'Name','contact_info',
        @{ l = 'signing_certificate_id'; e = { $_.sso_initialization_and_signature_policy.signing_certificate_id }}
    )
} | Export-Csv path\to\myexport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```